# Does Microsoft InTune work with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, intune

Does anyone here know if InTune works with AAD B2C?

I’ve been unable to find any documentation that explicitly answers this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about InTune managing devices for B2C local accounts, then that is not supported today. [enter link description here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/36947101-intune-for-b2c-same-as-aadb2c-is-for-aad)

Comment: Razi you are correct and I’ve confirmed with MS that it is not supported.